# Dynamic imports based on date

Tags: powerbi

I have a date slicer on the dashboard:

1. I want to display and import by default the current year's data pulled from the
   data source.
2. BUT, if someone selects the previous year's date from the
   calendar slicer I have, the script pulls out that data from the
   source as well

For example, by default, the calendar slicer shows this year (2023)
But I want to review 2020 data as well, so when I click on a date in 2020, the script pulls up the data from the source and displays it on the dashboard

Is it possible to do that in Power BI? My data source is Google Sheets

What I have tried so far:

- I have tried incremental refresh, it pulls 3 months of data while
  archiving the rest of the data so a user cannot click on the data and
  select the dates for previous years

Comment: Why not just load all the data from the source into your dashboard?

Comment: This is what we are doing currently, but as the data increases every time the dashboard is refreshed or initialised, it will take some time for it to load. Just want to optimize the performance of the dashboard